# Change attr value on screen resize

Tags: javascript, jquery

Say I have a table, and I wanna change attr to true on page resize. 
My current code ain't working.

```
<table data-toggle="table"
       data-pagination="true"
       data-search="true"
       data-show-toggle="true"
       data-show-columns="true"
       data-card-view="false">
<thead>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
    if ($(window).width() < 990) {
        $('table').attr('data-card-view', 'true')
    } else {
        $('table').attr('data-card-view', 'false')
    }
    }
)})
```

Comment: Please include what you mean by "ain't working". What is not working? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Are there any errors in the developer console?

Comment: The attr val doesn't get updated @CherryDT

Comment: OK, but what is the answer to the question about errors? Did you check the console?

Comment: In my browser the code executes exactly as you want using a direct copy/paste. What browser are you using?

Comment: Is that Javascript in a script tag, or just in your HTML like that?

Comment: no error in console @CherryDT

Comment: of course in script tag, using chrome @RayfenWindspear

Comment: @agDev I guessed so now already, please check my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that the attribute *is* changed correctly, did you check in your browser's devtools?

I guess the problem that your table's card view didn't update *even though the attribute changed*!

That's because bootstrap's custom "magic attributes" which cause special things to happen on your HTML elements will only be parsed when the page loads or when you explicitely ask bootstrap to do it.

In fact, there is already a function to switch between card view and normal view: `.bootstrapTable('toggleView')`

```
if(($(window).width() < 990) != $('table').bootstrapTable('getOptions').cardView) {
    $('table').bootstrapTable('toggleView');
}
```

Explanation: `if((condition x) != (condition y))` is a shorthand for `if((condition x && !condition y) || (!condition x && condition y))`. In my example it works without parens around the second condition because `something < 990` will evaluate to either `true` or `false` so I can directly compare it with the boolean member `cardView`.

Check out the [documentation](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/documentation/#methods).

Comment: What I was looking for. Thanks bro!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution in Javascript (Vanilla). Check if there is no other 'onresize' event or this one can be override.

```
var table = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];
window.onresize = function() {
  if (window.innerWidth < 990)
    table.setAttribute('data-card-view', 'true');
  else
    table.setAttribute('data-card-view', 'false');
}
```

Comment: Just a heads up, you copy/pasted true in both if/else.

Answer (score -3):

I think it' a syntax error.
Check this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() < 990) {
           $('table').attr('data-card-view', 'true');
        } else {
           $('table').attr('data-card-view', 'false');
        }
    });
});
```

You don't close the `.resize()` and the `.ready()` functions.

Add fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1kon3dfk/1/

Comment: The semicolons were in the code of OP before and for some reason edited out, but anyway the code should work with and without semicolons. And he does close the resize and ready properly, your code is neater but not any different in execution.

Comment: @CherryDT you right. I've add the 2 error that I think give the errors.

Comment: @zoubida13: Originally it was without semicolons and with wrong indentation, but I fixed it. Then I saw this answer and I thought maybe I accidentally removed a syntax error in my format fix, so I rolled back the fix. But now it appears there is no syntax error after all...? Because reading this answer again, I don't think this is the case, because the `}` for resize was there, one line below the `if`'s `}`, and the corresponding `)` was confusingly one line further down next to the `ready`'s `})`.

Comment: Right, his indentation was bad, but syntax was ok.

Comment: @CherryDT can you give us a fiddle?

Comment: @Daniele Petrarolo https://jsfiddle.net/1kon3dfk/ (move the splitter around, and it changes red<->green)

Comment: Yes of course, your code works the same and looks nicer; my point was just that the original code also works and there is no syntax error.